# SSRS Most Common Text Value

Tags: sql, reporting-services, count, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions

Looking for a SSRS expression (or other method) of finding the most common text value. Need to show what task an employee is assigned the most.

Table

```
Name      Task
Joe   |  Cleaning
Steve |  Sweeping
Steve |  Sweeping
Joe   |  Sweeping
Joe   |  Cleaning
```

Desired output

```
Name     Task
Joe   | Cleaning
Steve | Sweeping
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, you can do this with aggegation and window functions:

```
select name, task
from (
    select name, task, rank() over(partition by name order by count(*) desc) rn
    from mytable
    group by name, task
) t
where rn = 1
```

Note that this allows ties, if any.

Another approach uses `top`:

```
select top (1) with ties name, task
from mytable
group by name, task
order by rank() over(partition by name order by count(*) desc)
```